# populate filtered choices in combobox using wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to filter combobox choices based on the entered input and assigning new list of choices. Choices i am able to assign, but try to assign value it is giving below error:
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 6372)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WORK\ATEWorkSpace\TRY_ERROR\combobox_working.py", line 31, in text_return
    self.st.setValue(textEntered)
AttributeError: 'ComboBox' object has no attribute 'setValue'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WORK\ATEWorkSpace\TRY_ERROR\combobox_working.py", line 31, in text_return
    self.st.setValue(textEntered)
AttributeError: 'ComboBox' object has no attribute 'setValue'

My code is as below:

## !/usr/bin/python

## 20_combobox.py

```
import wx
import wx.lib.inspection

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.choices = ['grandmother', 'grandfather', 'cousin', 'aunt', 'uncle', 'grandson', 'granddaughter']
        for relative in ['mother', 'father', 'sister', 'brother', 'daughter', 'son']:
            self.choices.extend(self.derivedRelatives(relative))
        self.st = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, choices = self.choices, style=wx.CB_SORT)

        self.st.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.text_return)
        self.ignoreEvtText = False

    def text_return(self, event):
        if self.ignoreEvtText:
            self.ignoreEvtText = False
            return
        filteredList=[]
        textEntered=event.GetString()   

        if textEntered:
            matching = [s for s in self.choices if textEntered in s]
            self.st.Set(matching)
            self.ignoreEvtText = True 
            self.st.setValue(textEntered)
        else:
            self.st.Set(self.choices)        

    def derivedRelatives(self, relative):
        return [relative, 'step' + relative, relative + '-in-law']

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, '20_combobox.py')
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Please anybody suggest me what is wrong with code?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a typo.
Use `SetValue()`, `SetSelection()`, `SetString()`, `SetStringSelection()`
Your code is using `setValue()` instead of `SetValue()`